# Error: some required components are missing: prob?

Tags: r, r-caret

I followed this guideline for creating my own caret model [Creating Your Own Model](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html). There it states that

> If a regression model is being used or if the classification model
>   does not create class probabilities a value of NULL can be used here
>   instead of a function

and so I do that

```
# Define the model cFBasic
cFBasic <- list(type = "Regression",
                library = c("lubridate", "stringr"),
                loop = NULL)
...
cFBasic$prob <- NULL
cFBasic$sort <- NULL
```

However, when I attempt testing the model the following error is produced:

```
control <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                        number = 10, 
                        p = .9, 
                        allowParallel = TRUE)
fit <- train(x = calib_set,
             y = calib_set$y,
             method = cFBasic,
             trControl = control)
Error: some required components are missing: prob
```

How can I fix that? other than adding the function prob to generate a fake `pro` data frame to make `caret` happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By typing `cFBasic$prob <- NULL`, you are not actually adding a new item to your list.

Look at this:

```
cFBasic <- list(prob = NULL)
cFBasic
#> $prob
#> NULL

cFBasic$prob <- NULL
cFBasic
#> named list()
```

When you assign NULL to an object of a list, you delete that object. If you want to add a NULL object called `prob` and one NULL object called `sort` to a list you should type this way:

```
# Define the model cFBasic
cFBasic <- list(type = "Regression",
                library = c("lubridate", "stringr"),
                loop = NULL)
...
cFBasic <- c(cFBasic, list(prob = NULL))
cFBasic <- c(cFBasic, list(sort = NULL))
```

Have a try.